# .NET Framework automation on Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops

What all tasks should I use to create a build pipeline for .NET Framework solution? I want to add specific settings for each task.

Comment: If you would have googled it you would have found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4?view=azure-devops) microsoft tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find many yaml templates here: [azure-pipelines-yaml/templates/](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/tree/master/templates), [.NET Desktop](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/templates/.net-desktop.yml)

For the classic pipelines just use predefined templates:

1. Create a new pipeline:

[image]

2. Select a source
3. Select a template

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a solution like this one.